«α1-блокатор» или «α1-Блокатор» в начале предложения?
Как следует писать термин "α1-блокатор", если он находится в начале предложения? Должна ли "б" быть прописной?

• Буква б после дефиса никак не может быть прописной (если только это не имя собственное: Алла-Виктория, Баден-Баден, Гусь-Хрустальный).
В ПАС под ред. Лопатина такие объяснения и примеры:

§ 111. Дефис
3. Дефис употребляется в составе письменных эквивалентов сложных слов, часть которых передается цифрой, буквой или буквами (в том числе нерусского алфавита) или иным начертанием (даже таким, которое невозможно «прочесть»), напр.: 25-процентный, 150-летие, 300-миллионный, 5-1/2-тысячный, Т-образный, IBM-совместимый, γ-активный, «S-образное движение ловкого тела» (Купр.), ww-образные трубки.

Примеры:  альфа-блокатор (α-блокатор), бета-блокатор (β-блокатор), нейроблокатор, холиноблокатор.
• В начале предложения букву альфа, думаю, можно записать заглавной, если уж такая глобальная надобность возникла: А1-блокатор.
Такие буквы имеются и в греческом, и в латинском алфавитах: A, α.
Дополнение (17.08.2024)
• Из комментария: "Надписи Т-образный, S-образное здесь не образец..."
Конечно же, образец. Он отмечен, чтобы было видно, что в слове, начинающемся с прописной буквы, после дефиса все равно идет строчная буква.
✦ А вообще-то единичку в специальных текстах чаще всего пишут внизу символа (см.).
Тогда, считаю, правильно так: Альфа1-блокатор, α1-блокатор (справочник).

Думаю, что записать А1-блокатор невозможно, в этой записи никак нельзя узнать α1-блокатор (совпадение букв разных алфавитов), а это специальный ТЕРМИН в медицине. К примеру, я никогда не видела записи Г-лучи, пишут Гамма-лучи  начале предложения. // Глобальная надобность выглядит вполне понятно — это запись термина начале предложения. Поэтому желательно найти пример такой записи в тексте с цифрами (А1-блокатор) в текстах по этой теме.

Надписи Т-образный, S-образное  здесь не образец, так как речь идет о форме этих букв. В каждой теме своя специфика использования прописных и строчных  букв. Г-активный, Г- лучи уж точно не напишут.

Практически все пишут  α1-блокатор, то есть  нет там подстрочного знака. Нет его и в вопросе. Ищите тогда стандарт, доказывайте свое единственно ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ решение, если уж так. В таких вещах самодеятельность нежелательна.

Стандарт: справочник ВИДАЛЬ (содержит описания лекарственных препаратов и активных веществ (под международными наименованиями), представленных на фармрынке России. Международный справочник лекарственных препаратов для медицинских работников). Доказательство: лекарство Беталок, инструкция по применению. https://www.vidal.ru/drugs/betaloc__5300.

Вот интересно, два варианта записи с  подстрочной цифрой (в первом случае)  и обычной:  Клинико-фармакологическая группа  Альфа1-адреноблокатор. Антигипертензивный препарат
Фармако-терапевтическая группа: Антигипертензивные средства; антиадренергические средства периферического действия; альфа1-адреноблокаторы.  https://www.vidal.ru/drugs/urapidil-j   Так что у медиков свои правила, и не нам в них разбираться.

Так и не разбирайтесь. Вопрос-то ведь был, собственно, о букве "б" — прописной или строчной. Именно об этом я подробно рассказала в своем ответе: с правилом и примерами. P. S. Вы же очень быстренько, сразу после моих изысканий, переделали свой ответ. Похвально.

Я провела свои "изыскания", а вы на ваши авторское право возьмите. Или как там это сейчас называется. К тому же у меня другой ответ и другая ссылка. // Утомили меня эти "Олимпийские игры" и борьба за золотую медаль. Возьмите ее себе. // Этому форуму давно уже нужны новые люди, да никто не приходит, а последние разошлись. Участникам знания интересны, а не олимпийское шоу. Хотя, надо признаться, у вас хорошая группа поддержки, так что продолжайте дальше ваши подробные рассказы с подробными примерами.  У меня  другая эстетика  и логика ответов.

Правильно:
В начале предложения: Альфа1-блокатор, в середине предложения: α1-блокатор.
Запись по образцу: Фармако-терапевтическая группа: Антигипертензивные средства; антиадренергические средства периферического действия; альфа1-адреноблокаторы.
Некорректно: α1-Блокатор в любой позиции, в том числе в начале предложения.
